# JMESPATH query expression for matching Value in an Array

Tags: json, jmespath

I have the following JSON

```
{
    “Record”: [
  {
    “FirstName": “John”,
    “LastName”: “Smith”,
    “City”: “Chicago”,
    “Possessions”: [
      {
        “Item”: “TV”
      },
      {
        “Item”: “XBOX-S”
      },
      {
        “Item”: “DVR”
      },
      {
        “Item”: “Setup Box”
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    “FirstName": “Jane”,
    “LastName”: “Doe”,
    “City”: “Seattle”,
    “Possessions”: [
      {
        “Item”: “DVR”
      },
      {
        “Item”: “PS5”
      },
      {
        “Item”: “FireStick”
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    “FirstName": “Jane”,
    “LastName”: “Lee”,
    “City”: “Dallas”,
    “Possessions”: [
      {
        “Item”: “TV”
      },
      {
        “Item”: “PS5”
      },
      {
        “Item”: “FireStick”
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

How do I get a table of `First Name` and `Last Name` by matching a particular possession (`"TV"`) using JMESPATH query?
I need to match the Value in the Array Possessions for each entry in the Record

I have tried using the following query, but it does not work,

```
Record[?contains(Possessions[].Item, `TV`) == `true`]
```

anyone knows how this request will work or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying should work; although it should be simplified to ```Record[?contains(Possessions[].Item, `TV`)]```. This said, your JSON is invalid, and that's maybe what is causing your issue. Your quotes are literal quotation marks, `“”`, ASCII 147 and 148 and not a double quote, `"`, ASCII 34. (https://www.ascii-code.com)

Comment: Thanks That worked, would you also know the query if I want to display the other values where this condition does not meet, like list of Records where the Possessions does not have the TV.

Comment: got it working
```Record[?!contains(Possessions[].Item, `TV`)]``` this returns the other values where Possessions list do not have TV